# python dict check if json keys value is empty

Tags: python, json, config

I would like to check if the values corresponding to json keys within my configuration files are empty before passing them along. How could i go about doing this

```
def setup_config() -> dict:
    if os.path.isfile("config.json"):
        with open("config.json") as cfg:
            myjson = json.load(cfg)
            if not ('output_directory' and not 'data_directory' and not ('log_directory' in myjson) and not len(
                    myjson['output_directory'])) or len(myjson['data_directory']) or len(myjson['log_directory']) == 0:
                logging.error("Enter directory information in configuration file")
                exit(0)
            cfg_values = {"output_directory": myjson.get("output_directory"),
                          "data_directory": myjson.get("data_directory"),
                          "log_directory": myjson.get("log_directory")}
            json.dumps(cfg_values)
            return cfg_values
    else:
        with open("config.json", "w") as jsonFile:
            cfg_values = {"output_directory": "",
                          "data_directory": "",
                          "log_directory": ""}
            json.dump(cfg_values, jsonFile)
            logging.error("Enter directory information in configuration file")
            exit(1)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post a sample input and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

In python `dict.get('key')` will return None if the the `key` does not exist.

```py
foo = {'a': 'hello'}
b = foo.get('b')
if b:
    # b exists, process b
else:
    # handle if b does not exist
```